# What is type of relationship between tables?

Tags: sql

I have table `Orders` and table `Recipients`:

Where `Orders` is:

```
| id | recipient_id
```

Where `Recipients` is:

```
id | user_id | address_id
```

So, one order can be assigned to one recipient.

An order has foreign key to `Recipients.id`.

By another side, `Recipients` can be related to some orders.

What is relationship between table then?

Comment: What do you mean by "By another side"? Do you mean there's another table you haven't shown which relates Recipients to Orders? If so you should edit your question and provide all the information you have. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: one-to-many relationship as a recipient can have multiple orders

Comment: Is it good structure? I dont consider so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Recipients.ID` has many to one relationship with the `Orders.ID`.

Comment: It is inverse relationship, but Orders -> Recipients?

Answer (score 1):

I think its one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 1):

It's a **one to many** relationship, AKA **1:n** relationship.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key:

> Multiple rows in the referencing (or child) table may refer to the
>   same row in the referenced (or parent) table. In this case, the
>   relationship between the two tables is called a [one to many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling)) between the referenced table and the referencing table.

Comment: It is inverse relationship, but Orders -> Recipients? So should I create an additional table?